# getting data from HTML code using loop

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to scrape data from a simple website and save it into a CSV file using python 2.7 with selenium but I'm stuck with one little problem.

As you can see below in the HTML, there are 2 classes `company` and `person`. Under the `company` class sometimes there are 3 person classes and sometimes there's only 1 or 4 hence it means that there is no sequence.

what should I do that every time I could get only the `persons` who  are under the specified company class?

```
<tr class="company">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="company">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="company">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="company">..</tr>
```

and data should be save in csv like this:

```
company1       person1
company1       person2 
company1       person3 

company2       person1 

company3       person1 
company3       person2
```

anybody help me out? which kind of loop should i use here? what will be logic?

Answer (score 0):

To get only persons which are inside the tr tag with class= 'company', you have to use a locator wich only selects that Webelements, for instance the following one:

```
persons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="company"]')
for person in persons:
    print (person.text)
```

This is an example how to print the persons, with some more effort you can save them in a csv file.

Comment: and what about persons of that company? actually i want the persons also who are under the specified company class

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are trying to achieve this with selenium. But more efficiently it would be to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) libs. They work with both 2.7 and 3.x versions of Python.

**Simple example for your problem:**

Ok, so the `html` looks like this:

```
<tr class="company"></tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="company"></tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="company"></tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="person">..</tr>
<tr class="company">..</tr>
```

**My previous code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(yourUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

companyPersons = {}
for company in soup.find_all('tr',{'class': 'company'}): # find all class'es with company
    for person in company.children: # finds all children tags, e.g. company has 2 childrens person1 and person2, so it will find both
        if company in companyPersons:
            companyPersons[company].append(person)
        else:
            companyPersons[company] = person
```

**Edit to previous answer**
I have checked the html and what is needed to get. Well the way is similar to what I wrote earlier, just with little tweaks.

```
test_dict = {}
for company in soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'regroworg'}):
    for child in company.find_all('span', {'class': 'regorgname'}):
        for person in company.find_next_siblings('tr', {'class': 'regrow'} != {'class': 'regroworg'}):
            if person['class'] != company['class']:
                if child.text not in test_dict:
                    test_dict[child.text] = [person.text]
                else:
                    test_dict[child.text].append(person.text)
            else:
                break
```

The code above works as you wrote. It should grab all the company's persons. This part in the code `{'class': 'regrow'} != {'class': 'regroworg'}` is doing all the magic for finding needed siblings.
And result will be similar to this:

```
test_dict['ABB Secheron Ltd.']
['\nMr. Emmanuel Mittay, Key Account Manager\nemmanuel.mittay@ch.abb.com\n41 58 586 25 09\n41 58 586 22 28']
```

And now you can write data to .CSV or anywhere else.

**Some issues with code that solves current problem**

Of course I think that it could be done better from performance view, but for current problem it should be fine. And I noticed that there is roughly 607 company's (but I'm not 100% sure about this number), but my code extracts 396 dictionary keys (e.g. that are company's). So I suggest to debug the code and fix it. But I think the code solves at least 50% of your problem, now just fix it to solve it in 100% by your self (I think it's easy to solve it). ;)

Comment: this is exact link form where i'm trying to scrape data: http://www.apta.com/previousmc/rail/previous/2016rail/registration/Pages/PreRegistrationList.aspx
and this is a screenshot of HTML: https://ibb.co/d3sJhH

Comment: and your given HTML code is not similar which i want to target